# fadeIn() and fadeOut() only hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

Tried using jQuery's nice `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions, but they only wait for the duration, then appear/disappear abruptly, without transitioning the opacity. My code:

```
if (someCondition) {
    elm.fadeIn(fade);
} else {
    elm.fadeOut(fade);
}
```

It is inside a function that fires on key up. The fade variable is a valid number (300).

**EDIT**: Here is the  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbvxN/)

Comment: jsfiddle please. Solving this requires both html and css.

Comment: Provide more code with `html`

Comment: Added Fiddle, check question...

Answer (score 0):

"It is inside a function that fires on key up. The fade variable is a valid number (300)."

300 is 300 milliseconds , or .3 seconds , not a very long fade....

try 3000 instead or  this will work as well:

```
if (someCondition) {
  elm.fadeIn("slow");
} 
else {
  elm.fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: he says he see's the action , its just "abruptly"  - anyway - with no example or html , all we can do is guess

Answer (score 0):

The fade parameter is how long the element will take to change it's opacity, it is NOT the delay before the transitions starts. If you want it to delay the start the transition use `delay()`

```
$(ele).delay(300).fadeOut
```